# Change value of css in components

Tags: css, reactjs

I am new to React/Javascript and can't really solve this issue for a day.

I have object with names of players.

```
let players = {'Amber', 'Thomas', 'Trump', 'Michael', 'Someone'};
```

Basically players is the input function where users type their names and I store them here.

And I have a css for displaying them as a grid.

```
const styles = {
   section: {
     display: 'grid',
     gridGap: '5px',
     boxSizing: 'border-box',
     borderColor: 'black',
     padding: '5px',
     gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(1, 1fr)',
}
```

I would like to change the **value** in  'repeat(**value**, 1fr)' when the length of players increases.
In volleyball, there are six members in each team, so:

```
style = {list.length > 6 ? changeValueMoreSix : changeValueSixOrLess
```

I would like to separate them each six in case there are more players.

E.g.
Case1: Just 5 player, it should display:

```
Player1
Player2
Player3
Player4
Player5
```

Case 2: 11 Players:

```
Player1   Player7
Player2.  Player8
Player3   Player9
Player4   Player10
Player5   Player11
Player6
```

Basic idea is to create a column if it exceeds more than 6, 12, 18, etc, or column = player.length / 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to calculate value based on length of the list in `repeat(**value**, 1fr)`, you can use CSS values, attached in inline style of wrapper of list elements:

Calculate column amount (based on list length and `6` divider;

```js
const columnAmount = Math.ceil(list.length / 6);
```

Then, use this value in your template:

```html
<section 
  class="list-wrapper" 
  style={{ --column-amount: this.props.columnAmount }}
>
  <!-- list items  -->
</section>
```

And update your CSS:

```js
const styles = {
   section: {
     display: 'grid',
     gridGap: '5px',
     boxSizing: 'border-box',
     borderColor: 'black',
     padding: '5px',
     gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(var(--column-amount, 1), 1fr)',
}
```

where `--column-amount` in `var(--column-amount, 1)` is dynamic CSS value, `1` is callback value.

Comment: Hey man, thank you a lot. It is what I have been looking for!

Comment: hey, would you please give me the source of documentation where I can read more about this, please?

Comment: @MarkEzberg Using CSS variables with JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#values_in_javascript and CSS var itself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var

Answer (score 1):

You could create css classes for each required number (6, 12 etc):

```
.lessThanSix {
    gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(1, 1fr)',
}

.moreThanSix {
    gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(2, 1fr)',
}
```

And in js file conditionally change class of component, for example:

```
let currentClass = "";
list.length > 6 ? currentClass = moreThanSix : currentClass = lessThanSix;
```

Finally you'll get as more classes as many cases you have. You can change classes in switch/case block.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I am sure there must be a way to change the 'repeat(value, 1fr)' where value is 1, 2, or anything based on the length of the list. 
I don't think I need to create six css classes if length of the list is 6*6.

Can I set the value of value in 'repeat(value, 1fr)' based on the length of list?